# Can't read input from keyboard

Tags: 2d, sdl, input

I'm new to game dev,and I just trying to create my first game,a simple pong game.But i can't handle the keyboard input.

This is what i got :

```
const Uint8 * keystates = SDL_GetKeyboardState(NULL);
SDL_PumpEvents();

if (_keystates[SDLK_s])
    std::cout << "Down is pressed";
```

But if i run it and press 's',nothing ever happens.

```
if (_keystates[SDLK_RETURN])
    std::cout << "Return is pressed";
```

For this one is working just when i press 'j'... Yeah,right?

And more,if I add this line :

```
if (_keystates[SDLK_DOWN])
    std::cout << "Bla bla..";
```

My game crashes,what do you think is the problem?Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it says on the [SDL documentation](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_GetKeyboardState), `SDL_GetKeyboardState` returns an array of the keyboard state, with `SDL_SCANCODE` values as indices. You can't use the `SDLK_` values, they won't reference the right values. So change your code to use the `SDL_SCANCODE` values. There is a reference page [here](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_Scancode).

Your if-statement should then look like `if (_keystates[SDL_SCANCODE_RETURN]) {...}`.